# Obter endereço da rua a partir da latitude e da longitude

Tags: google-maps

É possível recuperar o endereço de uma avenida ou rua, apenas com a latitude e longitude?

Eu sei que o inverso e possível, mas não encontro nada como recuperar o nome da avenida, bairro ou cidade através da latitude e longitude.

Comment: Veja: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511597/how-to-get-address-location-from-latitude-and-longitude-in-google-map

Comment: É interessante também você informar qual a linguagem de programação você está se referindo para podermos dar um direcionamento correto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edvaldo, um exemplo bem legal desta aplicação, você pode conferir em:
[Convert Lat and Long to Address](http://www.latlong.net/Show-Latitude-Longitude.html) Ele utiliza uma API do próprio google maps para realizar a busca do endereço.

Espero que ajude :)

Comment: Olá, Ivo. Se você entende como o site que você apontou funciona, coloque código na sua resposta mostrando como se faz. Afinal, o autor provavelmente vai querer saber como se faz e não apenas se é possível. Mesmo se não for o caso dele, provavelmente será o de outras pessoas que chegarem aqui pesquisando isso.

Comment: Ok, Pablo. estou no começo da carreira no Stack. Valeu pela dica ;)

Comment: Muito util essa solução